# Failed to disable shortcut on ubuntu14.04 and debian8

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I used:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings close "[]"
```

to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> respectively.

In Ubuntu 14.04: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> worked, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> failed (meaning the `gsettings` succeeded but the short-cut is still active)

In Debian 8: Both <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> failed

*How can I solve this problem?* (Or is there  another way to disable short-cuts through the command line?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the same key binding to try to do different things: the correct ones are:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings close "[]"
```

If you did that already, try setting then to something ridiculously complex like  ['Above_Tab'] that you will never type by accident, as your goal is to not type it accidentally...

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Sorry about spelling error, gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings close "[]"  is the command i used. But there is no effect.

Comment: Have you tried setting them to something ridiculously complex like ['<Ctrl><Alt><Shift><Super>Above_Tab'] that you will never type by accident?  (If your goal is to never type it by accident.  If not: What *is* your goal?)

Comment: Hello?  You were here on Sept 2...  Could you clarify?

Comment: Favour returned...